# From QString to Class type

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have quite a good amount of classes all derived from the same parent and am in need of instantiating any of those from a simple QString

I imagined using a QMap with a QString key and "reference" to the class as value would do the trick

```
class Feat : public QObject { ... } // Base class

QMap<QString, ...> feats;
```

But i don't how where to go from here, what is the syntax to get what i want.

Comment: How are they constructed (what arguments?  What steps?)?  What do you do with them after they are constructed?  Do you know what inheritance is, and understand the LSP?  You are not sufficiently describing the problem.

Comment: I didn't think arguments would matter since they all have the same constructor definition. I know the principle of inheritance, never heard of LSP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your classes inherit from `QObject`, you could use the [`QMetaType` system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details) to construct instances from their name as a string. The meta-object system is a crucial part of Qt, and provides a mapping between type *names* and type *IDs*.

You need to first register your type, so that the meta-object system knows how to handle it, using:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Feat)
```

Then, whenever you want to construct an object by its name, you would use:

```
int type_id = QMetaType::type("Feat");
void *obj = QMetaType::create(type_id);
```

Now `obj` points to a dynamically-allocated instance of `Feat`. Note that you'll need to release the object when you are finished (using `QMetaType::destroy(type_id, obj);`); wrap it in a guarded pointer of some kind (`std::unique_ptr`, `QPointer`, etc.); or ensure that it has a `QObject` parent which will automatically release it.

Also, note that you need to register each type that you'd like to use in this way.

Comment: That seems quite interesting, i realize that i knew about metatype for qvariant use but i didn't know about that. So i need to register each derived type of "Feat" then ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` for each type you'd like to use in the meta-object system. It's a bit annoying, but it sounds like the additional flexibility would be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

As the constructor isn't a "normal" function, you need something like the factory pattern, i.e. to store functions that return a new instance of the given type; a trivial C++11+ way to do this is to map a `QString` to an `std::function` returning the new instance (as a pointer to the base class):

```
QMap<QString, std::function<Feat *()>> feats;
feats["Feat1"] = []() { return new Feat1; };
feats["Feat2"] = []() { return new Feat2; };
```

adjust as required if you need to pass in parameters to construct, or if you'd prefer to return some smart pointer (e.g. a `unique_ptr`). Also, depending on your taste you may or may not prefer to hide this code behind a macro.

```
#define REGISTER_FEAT(FeatClass) feats[#FeatClass] = []() { return new FeatClass;}
// to be used as
REGISTER_FEAT(Feat1);
REGISTER_FEAT(Feat2);
```

You may also avoid the `std::function` overhead if you are sure you won't need to capture anything in those lambdas, but I wouldn't worry about this unless you have some real reason (build times? runtime overhead?) to avoid it.

---

Incidentally, Qt containers are acknowledged even by Digia as in "life support mode", so, unless you have cogent reasons to use them (e.g. stable binary interface, more consistent performance across different compilers - albeit usually worse), you are generally better served by the builtin, "STL" counterparts (such as `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`).

Comment: Regarding predictable performance: I'd say quite the opposite is true, standard containers have more predictable performance as you know exactly when you'll make a copy wheras with Qt's COW containers even a range-based for loop or reading access via index may or may not cause a copy if the container is not `const`.

Comment: @Corristo: hmm I think "predictable" is indeed the wrong term; I'd say "consistent across compilers" (as you are using the same library in all cases, unlike the standard library, that is completely different between g++/libstdc++, clang/libc++, VC++/Dinkumware).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: "adjust as required [...] if you'd prefer to return some smart pointer"; this is just the general idea, the details depend from exactly how OP is going to use this - in particular, dealing with `QObject`-derived classes often you just return raw pointers to already-parented objects (in this case the parent would of course need to be passed in as a constructor parameter), so there would be no need for a smart pointer.

Comment: Alright i am gonna try that as soon as i can, thanks, and yes, raw pointers seems to be perfectly fine when using QObject derived class, as much as i can tell from what i learned so far.